# Get all row ids in one string in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table in SQLite which contains some data.
Like this

```
Table id
       1
       2  
       3
       4
       5
       6
       7
```

what i want is a String which contains all the ids separated by a semicolon (`;`) character, like

```
 1;2;3;4;5;6;7
```

I know there is group concat.
but I cannot figure out how to do that with this sample.

And there is another method called COALESCE I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string), but in SQLite we cannot declare variables.

Is there any way to do this in SQLite?

Comment: Please read about accessing SQLite DB in android.

Comment: i know we can get cursor and get all ids programmatically but i want to is there a way for do this in query?

Comment: `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id, ';') AS result
FROM tab` Is that what you need?

Comment: sorry some one else add comment and deleted immediately anyway in group concat must we have 'group by' at  the end right?

Comment: @max We can but if not provided it will get all records in one group, if you need filtering add sth like `WHERE id < 8`

Comment: oh i do not know that thanks

Comment: if you write i accept that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation function [`group_concat(X,Y)`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) to achieve it:

> The group_concat() function returns a string which is the
>   concatenation of all non-NULL values of X. If parameter Y is present
>   then it is used as the separator between instances of X. A comma (",")
>   is used as the separator if Y is omitted. The order of the
>   concatenated elements is arbitrary.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id, ';') AS result 
FROM tab_name
-- WHERE id < 10; -- if needed
```

If you don't specify `GROUP BY ...` clause all records will be treated as one group.